# FFMPEG not working after upgrade php version from 5.2 to 5.3.28

Tags: ffmpeg, php

After upgrade php version DL() function is not working.

I have tried with extension=extension.so in php.ini its working but below command

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.m4v -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 480x320 output.mp4
```

Gives error

Unknown encoder 'libx264'

Below is full description

```
root@server [~]# ffmpeg -y -i input.m4v -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 480x320 output.mp4
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 30 2012 00:00:18 with gcc 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --disable-indev=v4l2 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -m64 -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libavcodec  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libavformat configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libavdevice configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libavfilter configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libswscale  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --disable-yasm
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.36. 0
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.12. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 60000.00 (60000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/machine/public_html/sterlingadmin/files/video_1402351414.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2014-05-16 22:20:14
    title           : a3343_Spanish
  Duration: 00:07:11.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4488 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 114 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-05-16 22:20:14
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 960x540 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4369 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-05-16 22:20:14
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your PHP version. Your ffmpeg version itself isn't compiled with x264 support. Please show the full output, not just the command itself. Also tell us about your OS / distribution.

Comment: Please check full comand execution edited the question

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you running? Which kernel? Your ffmpeg is terribly outdated, and you should ideally use one from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html instead. But then you'd also need to change your command lines a bit, because they've changed in syntax and functionality. I suspect (since you've been running PHP 5.2 too) that your distribution and kernel are *quite* outdated too, so you might want to update the entire thing.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b7.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jun 12 03:34:52 UTC 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [static builds of ffmpeg hosted here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) which even run on legacy systems (kernels 2.6.32 and above). You can download it, and put the `ffmpeg` binary in some place on your filesystem, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`.

Then, from PHP, call `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` instead of your system ffmpeg. The benefit is that you now run a recent version with less bugs and more functionality.

You need to update your command line though, since the `-vpre` option no longer exists.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i input.m4v -c:v libx264 -s:v 480x320 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 64k output.mp4
```

Since it seems you're targeting devices with lower processing capabilities, use the `baseline` profile.

Comment: Its gives Unrecognized option 'c:v'

Comment: Then you're using the wrong ffmpeg version. If you use the one downloaded from the link (the static build), it will recognize the option `c:v`. Make sure that in your PHP `exec` call, you call the right ffmpeg you downloaded, by supplying the full path to it.